# WebView postMessage communication delay with iframe

Tags: javascript, android, iframe, webview, postmessage

I have a webview contain iFrame with angular app and they communicate with each other. 
After I removed the iFrame element and re-open, I noticed that the communication is very "slow", I profile the CPU and saw ±1 sec of idle between the post msg from webview to the receive on iFrame and reverse.
This happens only on part of Android devices and not in the first time I run the iFrame.
Any idea?

Comment: Could you provide your code so we can see what's going on?

Comment: This is a problem, it's a big application, but I only use in $window.addEventListener("message", receiveMessage, false) and $window.parent.postMessage(data, "*") . When I create a clean iFrame to test with the webview it's work fine all the time.